# Сохранить текст из textField1 в DB

Tags: java

Всем привет, есть у меня такая сложность, сохранить должно в `arrayList`, но не сохраняет из-за несоответствия типов, что-ли... Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

```
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setTovarList(textField1.getText()); // Ошибка
            try {
                dbHalper.writeModel(model); // добавили пользователя в базу данных
            } catch (Exception e1)

            public class Model {

                ArrayList < Saless > salessArrayList = new ArrayList < Saless > ();
                public ArrayList < Saless > getSalessArrayList() {
                    return salessArrayList;
                }
                public void setSalessArrayList(ArrayList < Saless > salessArrayList) {
                    this.salessArrayList = salessArrayList;
                }

                ArrayList < Tovar > tovarList = new ArrayList < Tovar > (); {}
                public ArrayList < Tovar > getTovarList() {
                    return tovarList;
                }
                public void setTovarList(ArrayList < Tovar > tovarList) {
                    this.tovarList = tovarList;
                }

                ArrayList < Saler > salerArrayList = new ArrayList < Saler > ();

                public ArrayList < Saler > getSalerArrayList() {
                    return salerArrayList;
                }
                public void setSalerArrayList(ArrayList < Saler > salerArrayList) {
                    this.salerArrayList = salerArrayList;
                }


                public Model() {}

                public Model(ArrayList < Saless > salessArrayList, ArrayList < Tovar > tovarList, ArrayList < Saler > salerArrayList) {
                    this.salessArrayList = salessArrayList;
                    this.tovarList = tovarList;
                    this.salerArrayList = salerArrayList;
                }
            }

            public class Tovar {

                int price;

                public int getPrice() {
                    return price;
                }

                public void setPrice(int price) {
                    this.price = price;
                }

                public Tovar() {}

                public Tovar(int price) {
                    this.price = price;
                }

                public void priceTovar() {
                    price = price + 100;
                }
            }
```

> Information:09.05.2015 9:20 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0
>   warnings in 25 sec
>
> Error:(32, 54) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to java.util.ArrayList
>
> C:\Users\Андрей\IdeaProjects\TSSDB\src\Form2.java
>
> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'TSSDB'
>
> Information:java: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -
>
> Xdiags:verbose to get full output
>
> Information:Using javac 1.8.0_40 to compile java sources

Comment: Без логов ошибки мы вам никак не поможем.

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev                                                                            Начал учить недавно, имею поверхностное понимание  "логи", вот ошибку которую дает, спасибо                                                                                                 Error:(32, 54) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<Tovar>

Comment: Вы можете добавить информацию об ошибке в вопрос. В идеале ещё стоит привести код класса `Model`

Comment: Добавил класс Модел, Товар, и информацию об ошибке... думаю, несоответствие типов, но как его тогда привести в нужный тип не понимаю..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error:(32, 54) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList
```

Это означает, что у тебя не может `String` сконвертироваться в `ArrayList`. И это вполне правильно, потому что в `textField` у тебя хранится строка, а `model` в методе `setTovarList` у тебя в качестве параметра должен быть `ArrayList<Tovar>`. Если же ты хочешь добавить в `model` именно товар, то ты должен сначала создать объект `Tovar`, далее положить его в `ArrayList<Tovar>`, а уже далее записывать в модель